# Do while loop determined by users input c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I have a lottery game where I am trying to determine the amount of lines the users has entered.E.G They enter 4, they receive 4 sets of 5 random numbers. I am trying to use a do while loop but do not know where to enter the variable in the loop?

```
        public static void EuroDraw()
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("How many lines do you wish to purchase (minimum 1):");
            int euroLines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {   
                int[] EuroMillions = new int[5];
                Random EuroNumbers = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < EuroMillions.Length; i++)
                {
                    EuroMillions[i] = EuroNumbers.Next(1, 50);
                }
                Array.Sort(EuroMillions);

            Console.WriteLine("Your Euro Millions Numbers are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < EuroMillions.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(EuroMillions[i]);
            } while (euroLines <= euroLines);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I have tried entering the while condition where the variable needs to equal the varialbe as seen above but it ends in a never ending loop.Any help much appreciated

Comment: A `for` loop would be a better candidate here. Replace the `do/while` loop with: `for(int euroLine = 0; euroLine < euroLines; euroLine++)`

Comment: As acerbic as j's comment was, they're not wrong.  If you're in a never-ending loop, then there's obviously an issue with your loop condition and that's something you need to check first.  It's pretty clear you're new at this, it's also pretty clear you're doing coursework.  So here's the big pro-tip: Being a good programmer isn't about knowing what code to type, it's about knowing how to plan processes/algorithms and how to work out why (and *where*) they don't do what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (euroLines <= euroLines);
```

(do you see it yourself?)

...

hint: a variable is always equal to itself, so this never becomes `false` --> infinite loop

So you need another variable which is increasing in the loop:

```
int euroLines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int currentLine = 1;  // <-- this
do
{   
    // ...
} while (++currentLine <= euroLines);
```